# How to use aiomultiprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, multiprocess

I found this package `aiomultiprocess` that seems like it can do both multiprocessing and asyncio.

```
from aiohttp import request
from aiomultiprocess import Pool


async def get(url):
    async with request("GET", url) as response:
        return await response.text("utf-8")


async def main():
    urls = ["https://jreese.sh", "https://www.google.com", ]
    async with Pool() as pool:
        async for result in pool.map(get, urls):
            print(result)
```

Trying to run the sample code, though, does absolutely nothing.

Trying to call the `main()` gives me an error `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited`. I can't find an actual example of how to trigger the code.

The only other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917273/aiomultiprocess-make-a-pool-but-it-doesnt-work) about this isn't answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399157/runtimewarning-coroutine-main-was-never-awaited)

Comment: The code sample I provided is from the documentation itself, so clearly I have read the docs. Unfortunately it's not a complete working example, so I'm looking for the last line that makes it work. @Carcigenicate I looked at that question, but my understanding is that answer directly calls the underlying package (asyncio) that this library (aiomultiprocess) probably wraps. There's probably a recommended way to do this using aiomultiprocess without using asyncio directly, because calling asyncio would defeat the purpose of this library?

Comment: I doubt it. I've never used that library, but you'll probably need `asyncio.run`, or one of the other core ways of dealing with coroutines.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks, that was it. The example was indeed incomplete. I'm using 3.6, so
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aiomultiprocess` documentation example does not cover how to call the loop. The function needs to be called via asyncio.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import request
from aiomultiprocess import Pool


async def get(url):
    async with request("GET", url) as response:
        return await response.read()


async def main():
    urls = ["https://jreese.sh", "https://www.google.com", ]
    async with Pool() as pool:
        async for result in pool.map(get, urls):
            print(result)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # for Python 3.7
    asyncio.run(main())
    
    # for Python 3.6
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(main())
```